# Login to slideshare

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, browser

I'm trying to create a tool to manage multiple slideshare accounts. It's pretty tiresome to login and logout of each of them manually, so a thought to create a simple webbrowser tool that does the login for me.

Problem is, when I try to hit the login button it tells me the 'fields need to be populated' (and they are) then when i focus the control and try to press the login manually (from within the webbrowser control) i tells me that it's 'invalid username/password combination'

I even took it a step firther and deleted the text from the inputs and repasted the same ones from a text file, but the same 'invalid user/pass' massage appears.

When I try yo do this manually from an actual IE browser, it logs in no problem. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub targetSlideshare()
    Dim details() As String
    details = accounts(currentAcc).Split(":")
    user = details(0)
    pass = details(1)
    Label19.Text = (currentAcc + 1).ToString + "/" + accounts.Length.ToString

    status = "Logout"
    Label20.Text = status
    loaded2 = False
    WebBrowser2.Navigate("https://www.slideshare.net/logout")
    While loaded2 = False
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    status = "Logging In"
    Label20.Text = status
    loaded2 = False
    WebBrowser2.Navigate("https://www.slideshare.net/login")
    While loaded2 = False
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser2.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser2.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If status = "Logout" Then
        loaded2 = True
    ElseIf status = "Logging In" Then
        WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("user_login").SetAttribute("value", user)
        'WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("user_login").SetAttribute("placeholder", Nothing)
        WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("user_password").SetAttribute("value", pass)
        'WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("user_password").SetAttribute("placeholder", Nothing)
        Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser2.Document.All
        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Login" Then
                status = "Loading"
                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next

        loaded2 = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to that site from the PC i'm currently at, but the following works for me to login to Google:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://www.google.com/")
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").InnerText = user.ToString
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Passwd").InnerText = pass.ToString
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signIn").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

One other trick that might be helpful:

I've found when I'm having problems logging in through the webbrowser control on some desktop sites trying to the automate the login on the mobile version ie: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/login sometimes works.

Comment: I have no trouble signing in to other websites, it works perfectly. I just don't understand why it acts like this on slideshare. I don't see any code mistakes.

Also, the mobile link just shows the page code, I can't use it with a webbrowser.